# Why I'm not able to replace the HTML content in AJAX success response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Following is the code I've :

jQuery AJAX function code :

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var br_id = $('#brand_id').val();
  var status = '0';
  var module_url = $('#module_url').val();
  var upload_url = $('#upload_url').val();
  var formdata = false;
  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'manufacturers.php',
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

    success: function(response) { 
      if(response.error == 0) {  
        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.error_message);

      } else { 
        $('#BrandImageModal').modal('hide');

        var newdiv = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_'+br_id+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a>';
        var newtd  = '<img src="'+upload_url+text(response.image_path)+'" width="80" height="80">';
        var $div = $(newdiv); // use jQuery to parse the HTML
        $div.click(function(e) { // use jQuery for event listeners
          change_promotion_status(module_url, promotion_status, br_id, '0');
          return false;
        });
        $("div #brand_"+br_id ).html( newdiv );
        $("td #brand_image_td_"+br_id ).html( newtd );       
      }
    },
    dataType:"JSON"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to change the HTML content of  and  with certain ids. But unfortunately I'm not able to replace these content. I don't want to reload the page. The content should get replaced without reloading the page at all. 
Can someone please guide me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you debug the code within the success handler?

Comment: can you log the value of `$("div #brand_"+br_id ).length` same way `$("td #brand_image_td_"+br_id ).length` too

Comment: @ArunPJohny:After which statement should I put the above two statements in my code?

Comment: after `$('#BrandImageModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: @Daniel:Yes I debugged the code b y putting alert messages in if and else block. They are getting printed properly. That means the flow is proper.

Comment: @ArunPJohny:It gave me following error in firebug console:
ReferenceError: text is not defined
 

var newtd  = '<img src="'+upload_url+text(response.image_path)+'" width="80" hei...

Comment: what are you trying to do with `text(response.image_path)`... there is no inbuilt method named `text`.... do you have a custom function by that name... change it to `response.image_path`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62791/discussion-between-phplover-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var newdiv = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_' + br_id + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a>';
//here there was no method called `text` causing a script error
var newtd = '<img src="' + upload_url + text(response.image_path) + '" width="80" height="80">';
var $div = $(newdiv); // use jQuery to parse the HTML
$div.click(function (e) { // use jQuery for event listeners
    change_promotion_status(module_url, promotion_status, br_id, '0');
    return false;
});
//the click event is bound to the dom element in $div not to the string newdiv
$("div #brand_" + br_id).html($div);
$("td #brand_image_td_" + br_id).html(newtd);
```